# Iterative cURL command - Batch File

Tags: loops, batch-file, curl

I am using a batch file to run a cURL command that uses a dynamically created json file as the payload.  I am looping through each file in a directory, and setting the `filename` variable, and using that for the `resp` variable.  However it seems that it's iterating for each file, but not resetting the `filename` and `resp` values.  See Script Below

```
@echo on
for %%f in ("C:\po_responses\*.json") do (
    set filename=@%%f
    set resp=%%~nf_response.json
    curl -g -H "Authorization:Bearer Token"  -H "content-type:application/json" -H "accept:application/json" -X POST -d "%filename%" https://api.clientsite.com/ -o "%resp%"
)
```

Comment: In your instance there is no need to create those two environmental variables.  Just use the `FOR` variable directly with your curl command.  That way you don't have to deal with delayed expansion which is explained in the duplicate question I linked to.

Comment: Also you must put `@` in front of the filename if you want its contents to be posted:  `-d @c:\po_responses\request1.json -o c:\po_responses\request1_response.json`

Comment: Also note, if you run this batch, it will attempt to post the responses back as well, creating a kind of infinite loop.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for the help and the guidance